# An expression in mathematics

Tags: word-meaning

> The mathematics is a kind of 'formal science'.

I have no idea about the meaning of the word, 'formal',in this expression.

From my perspectives,the word,'formal',should stands for some qualities like 'nothing to do with the essence','a series of connections linked by logics',etc.But I can't find such an explanation in my dictionary.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457). If the text is not quoted from someone else, please indicate this.

Comment: Generally, the word mathematics does not take "the": it is an abstract noun.

Comment: Wiktionary give "Relating to the form or structure of something. 
*"Formal linguistics ignores the vocabulary of languages and focuses solely on their grammar."* and specifically in maths "Relating to mere manipulation and construction of strings of symbols, without regard to their meaning."

Comment: Thanks for your correction

Comment: duplicate. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53969/871199

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not speak of mathematics  as "formal science". Strictly speaking I would not call it science at all, although much of science uses mathematics.

Mathematics can be formal or informal. formal mathematics strictly follows rules of reasoning, indicating each step clearly. Proofs, for example, are normally done in a formal style. In that context "formal" means following he defined rules and procedures exactly.

The word "formal" has different senses in different contexts. One can speak of an event or occasion as formal if social rules and patters are more strictly followed than at an informal or casual event. Formal language more carefully adheres to correct grammatical forms, and uses standardized phrases in many cases. There are other senses of "formal" as well.

Comment: I would call mathematics, as did Carl Friedrich Gauss, the 'queen of the sciences'. It is the purest and most rigorous of the sciences, and, as David Hilbert said, 'the foundation of all exact knowledge of natural phenomena'.

Comment: You will note that all of those are 19th-centuary or early 20th-centuary  statements. I believe that current usage would limit "science" to the natural sciences, such as physics, chemistry, Biology, psychology  and the social sciences such as anthropology.

Comment: Still an open question, with decided views on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

The 'formal' here need to be understood mathematically. (So are many other terms in a math book.) It means the 'math science' is about *axioms* and *deductions* using axioms and certain deduction rule(s), that is, no real-life means of gaining knowledge is taken into consideration when doing a math problem. That said, the nearest definition given by *[merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/formal)* is:

> relating to or involving the outward form, structure, relationships, or arrangement of elements rather than content.

As you can see in Hilbert's *[Foundations of Geometry](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ewodzicki/160/Hilbert.pdf)*, which is one of the most famous books written in the spirit of *formalisation* among mathematicians, every theorem is gained through rigorous logic deduction. Here, the method of drawing a picture to see something intuitively is not considered a valid proof<sup>[1]</sup>. However, methods like drawing a picture are widely used in other science or technology areas to help you get some result or prove something, which is one of the traits that differentiate 'formal' from 'not formal'.

Having some knowledge of [formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)), [mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic) and [formal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) may help you better understand the connotation of 'formal' in math. By the way, I feel like this question is more about philosophy of mathematics than English.

---

footnote:

[1] You may see there are some pictures in that book, but they are intended to help understanding rather than serve as a proof. In a research level math book, all pictures of geometric shapes, which are rare if not nonexist, can be removed without any reduce of the validity of the proofs there.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see more of the context within the paragraph. It sounds like it may be getting used in the sense of some kind of synonym. If you have access to a Thesaurus, that would probably be helpful to you.

For example, the adjective **formal** can have a sense of **scholarly** or **academic** depending upon contextual usage. It can also have meaning **systematic** or **authoritative**.